# How to display a textbox 'other' is selected in a combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

Here is the code of my program:

```
<div id="sp">
   <div style="line-height:22px;background:#fafafa;padding:5px;">Select a language</div>
    <div style="padding:10px">
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="01"><span>Java</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="02"><span>C#</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="03"><span>Ruby</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="04"><span>Basic</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="05"><span>Other</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#sp').appendTo($('#cc').combo('panel'));
        $('#sp input').click(function(){
            var v = $(this).val();
            var s = $(this).next('span').text();
            $('#cc').combo('setValue', v).combo('setText', s).combo('hidePanel');
        });
    });
</script>
```

If the user selects the 'Other' radio button I want to display a textbox so the user can enter the name of the other language.

Comment: Your code seems to require a plugin providing the `combo()` method; if that's relevant to the problem you're having, and want help with, please add a link to that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this

```
<span class='other'>Other</span> //add a class

$("#sp .other").click(function(){
   $("<input type='textbox' name='other'/>").insertAfter($(this))
})
```

Comment: hey.... i have tried your code but after selecting other as option i am not getting any text box.

Comment: have you added a class to the span element of "Other"

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will hep you.

```
<div id="sp">
    <div style="line-height: 22px; background: #fafafa; padding: 5px;">Select a language</div>
    <div style="padding: 10px">
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="01"><span>Java</span><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="02"><span>C#</span><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="03"><span>Ruby</span><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="04"><span>Basic</span><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lang" value="05"><span>Other</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sp').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $('#sp :radio:checked').val();

            if (selectedValue == "05") {
                var addedlangualge = prompt('Add New Language :');

                $('#sp').append('<input type="radio" name="lang" value="' + addedlangualge + '" checked="checked"><span>' + addedlangualge + '</span>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want to add a text box once a user select other option, where user will provide a language, which will be saved as user's language while submitting form Khanjan Bhatt